# How to write an PHP array into xls file?

Tags: php

My data looks like this (After clicking View Page Source),

```
date \t new_users \t cpm \t earnings \t total_pushes \t avail_users \t application \t 
 2011-03-31  \t  336933  \t  $5.27  \t  $10151.2  \t  1925244  \t  1905744  \t  Play Movies  \t 
 2011-03-31  \t  205070  \t  $5.12  \t  $5810.26  \t  1134946  \t  1118354  \t  Watch Movies or TV Shows  \t
```

I imploding given array with '\t' and then dynamically writing into xls file .Problem with this is all of the contents are present only in the first column of the xls file .

What am i missing in the code,does xls file requires data format ?

Comment: \t should not be visble, you should see a [tab]. Also, this wont be valid XLS, but a TSV file. But maybe if you show some more code we could help more.

Comment: @saratis is right.  Check your code to see if you use double quotes or single quotes around the `\t`.  It should be "double quotes".

Comment: $glue = '\t';
$h = array( 'date' , 'news' , 'cpm' , 'earnings' , 'pushes' , 'count' , 'app');
$top = implode("$glue",$h)."\n";

$d = array(
 '0'=> array('2011','3' ,'5.2','10151.2', '1925244','1905744','Play Movies'),
 '1'=> array('2011','2 ' ,'35.2', '10151.2', '1134946  ','1118354  ','Watch Movies or TV Shows')
 
);
$f_c= '';

 foreach ($d as $ed){
  $cs  = null;
        $cs  = implode("$glue" ,array_values($ed));
        $f_conts     .= $s. "\n";
 }
$f_cs =$top.$f_c;
$f = 's.xls';
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-disposition: filename=".$f);
print_r( $fn )

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use fputcsv to build your file.  You dont need to worry about setting the delimiter.  Then you should rename the file to something.xls.

If you're processing this from a web request, add the following header: application/vnd.ms-excel

```
<?php
// create header array here...$myHeaders
// create data array here... $myData

$csvName = 'temp.csv';

$fp = fopen($csvName, 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $myHeaders);
foreach ($myData as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);

// now send to browser if this is a web request
$csvData = file_get_contents($csvName);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($csvData));
echo $csvData;
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

For generating valid xml you can use f.e. the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

If you statisfied with simplier format, you can just generate csv file format. This is good enough for open or MS office.
For csv put the built content simply into a file, or use the [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not trying to write XLS but CSV (comma-separated value) format. If that's the case, replace `\t` with `,` (or `;`) and wrap all value fields (not the column titles) in double quotes (`"`).

Excel should handle CSV files formatted like that without a problem.

If you really want to generate an XLS file, try generating an HTML table with your data in it. Put the HTML code for that table into a single variable and use the following code to download it as an XLS-file automatically:

```
// Just some example data in a HTML table
$htmlcontent = "<table><tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr><tr><td>val1-1</td><td>val1-2</td></tr></table>";

// Create as XLS file and send to browser for download
$filename ="data.xls";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $htmlcontent;
```

That way, your users can download the content as an XLS file that Excel should be able to handle just fine.

(PS; you can try using the `\t`-separated data as file contents instead of an HTML table, that may work, but I'm not sure so give it a go.)